# 802.1x and Arduino Ethernet

Tags: arduino, ethernet, atmega

Arduino Ethernet does not seem to work on environments where [802.1x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) is deployed.

When connecting a Windows/Mac laptop to the same port, it is possible to "cancel" or not init a certificate authentication, in which case the enterprise can choose to connect the device to an "open" network.

Is it possible to provide this "basic" functionality with Arduino Ethernet?

What is the status of 802.1x in Arduino or an [ATmega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#Device_overview) microcontroller?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what shield/arduino you are using for the 802.1x?

Comment: I was referring to the Arduino standard ethernet shield.